# Column height in Column Layout in ExtJS 4

Tags: extjs

How to set columns' height in layout? I want to fill the Container where they are.

Answer (score 8):

Don't use `column` layout. Instead, use a `hbox` layout with `align: 'stretch'`

Comment: What if you really had to use a column layout instead? In my case, I need to because the column layout is the only layout that allows me to divide the layout in 2 equal halves using percentages (columnWidth: .05).

Comment: "the only layout that allows me to divide the layout in 2 equal halves". Incorrect. Use `flex: 1` on each item in a box layout. Equal widths.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli, unfortunately, it seems that using a layout of `hbox` for two child containers side by side (with overflow) will not create a single scrollbar in the parent element... instead, there would be 1 scrollbar for each container.